# Latex to HTML converter with specific needs

Tags: conversion, html

I have the task to find a tool that converts LateX to HTML.

I already had a look at different tools like Hevea, pandoc, Hyperlatex. The best looking tool for my needs was Hevea but lacks support for images on Windows.

**my requirements are:**

- working on windows (7)
- scriptable (batch script or something similar)
- splitting in multiple files on chapters
- possibilty to name the splitted files per chapter (e.g. \chapter{Rights & Permissions} -> login.html
- same .tex file should also be used to produce pdf

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `tex4ht`? It does easily support all your requirements, except renaming split chapter names (it could be done, but not easily and some stuff like cross-references might fail). Renaming can be done with some script replaces all hyperlinks to renamed file in all html files.

Try this command:

```
make4ht -u filename "xhtml,2"
```

the numeric parameter (2) directs which sectioning levels should be split to separate files. Possible variants are  1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: I tried this but the effort to make it work with the filenames was bigger than the solution I found for Hevea. There is a hevea.sty file to make it compliant with Latex (http://hevea.inria.fr/doc/manual007.html). And I made the image conversion/renaming with a small java file, since it is a documentation for a Java web project and I'm a java developer.